# Spring Authorization Server: Sending Opaque Token to Introspect endpoint returns "invalid_request"

Tags: spring-security, spring-authorization-server

I am migrating a project to Spring Authorization Server (1.0.0) and have hit an issue.

Despite the lack of much in the way of examples or documentation I have pressed ahead with trying to set it up to return Opaque tokens using the Authorization Code Flow (with PKCE).

I have managed to get the Scheme deployed and hook up all the services and have got to the point where my SPA can send a user to login on the Authorization server and use the code that comes back to get a token from the server.

The issues come when trying to send that access token to the introspect endpoint (I have not done any configuration on this it has been left as default).

Regardless of what tool I use (Spring Oauth2 Resource server or Postman) when I passs in the access token I am getting the following response.

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request"
}
```

I have confirmed that the access token exists in the oauth2_authorization table and that the correct client id & secret are being used (incorrect client id or secret on the introspection request returns a different error).

There are no errors shown in the console (regardless of log level) so I am getting a bit lost really.

The documentation seems really limited on this project so wanted to reach out to the community and see if anybody has any examples of how to setup opaque tokens or any ideas where I may be going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like we need an official sample or guide in the documentation to demonstrate this setup.

As it happens, we're presenting on this in our talk "Configuring and Extending Spring Authorization Server" at [SpringOne Essentials](https://springone.io/sessions/configuring-and-extending-spring-authorization-server) in a few days (Jan 26, 2023). I cover both opaque tokens and token introspection in the upcoming talk.

The general approach I took to configure the [Getting Started](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html#developing-your-first-application) example is as follows:

- Split the sample `RegisteredClient` into two clients called `oidc-client` and `messaging-client`
- Leave `oidc-client` configured for OIDC, meaning it will remain configured to use JWTs
- Change `messaging-client` to use opaque tokens with `.tokenSettings(TokenSettings.builder().accessTokenFormat(OAuth2TokenFormat.REFERENCE).build())`

The `oidc-client` would then be used just for logging in at the client, so it only needs scopes like `openid` and `profile`. The `messaging-client` would be used by the client to obtain an access token for accessing protected resources at the resource server, so it needs the scopes `message.read` and `message.write` in this example.

Splitting the `RegisteredClient` into two separate clients is necessary so that JWTs can continue to be used for the UserInfo endpoint[1].

See the following commits for the example:

- [Configure authorization server for opaque tokens](https://github.com/sjohnr/spring-authorization-server/commit/60a689a0828f9c143f4556f0586e4b23f08d6ac8)
- [Prepare messages-client and messages-resource server](https://github.com/sjohnr/spring-authorization-server/commit/54344ccdbe02305b8c3ae710b18378e5e0f303c9)

[1] **Note:** It is actually a bit more difficult (though very possible) to configure Spring Authorization Server to use opaque tokens for the UserInfo endpoint. It involves configuring an `OpaqueTokenIntrospector` from Spring Security to introspect tokens internally. This would be a fairly advanced setup and possibly somewhat confusing, so we chose not to try and cover it in the talk.

Comment: Thanks I'll try and catch that session but actually my setup is much simpler than what you have described (No OIDC or JWTs)! 

I have a react SPA (that uses a public client), redirects to login and then calls the auth server and get an opaque token (This all works).

The issue I'm hitting is that when I pass that key from the SPA to a resource server the resource server then tries to call the introspect endpoint on the auth server and I am getting an "Invalid request" error back. 

Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately not, without more information or debugging details. :-( Introspection of opaque tokens works using the above setup. You mention that you're not using OIDC but your SPA is logging in? The purpose of OIDC is to allow login. I would guess there's something amiss in your setup, though I don't know if it's related to this issue.

Comment: Actually, if you're using a SPA, I think that would imply you've configured a public client. See [this comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/796#issuecomment-1175418410). Token introspection **requires** client authentication, e.g. a client secret.

Comment: That's what I was missing, the existing project was badly setup! Thanks!